# Using Self hosted Kafka as event source for AWS Lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I want to use a self-hosted (in EC2 instance) Kafka stream to use as an event source to trigger the lambda function. Although lamda can easily be configured([here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/)) to get triggered from a Kafka stream, I don't want to trigger for all the messages but for only a few conditions.

We can use pattern matching in Eventbridge but can we use self-hosted Kafka as a source there? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your custom filtering somewhere. I think your best bet would be to use [Kafka Streams](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#streamsapi) to find the relevant messages which you want to act upon and then send them to a separate topic. Here's an [article](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/filter-a-stream-of-events/kstreams.html) explaining how this can be implemented.

Other alternative solutions I could suggest would be to use AWS Kinesis or a custom kafka consumer, nevertheless they all follow the same concept:

1. Process the stream.
2. Find the relevant messages.
3. Send them to some other place (e.g another kafka topic) which will be the input for your lambda.